# Access Denied on VS2012 Ultimate Uninstall

Tags: uninstall, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to uninstall VS2012 from my Windows 7 but it is giving me "Access Denied".

[image]

I have no antivirus installed on my machine plus Windows firewall is also off. Can you help me fixing this issue?

Edit: I am logged with Admin account.

Comment: Are you logged in as Administrator? Or another account with privileges to uninstall?

Comment: Check the error logs.  This is clearly a permission problem.